# Publish subdomain to list of ports using traefik

Tags: traefik

This is how I currently create a Couchbase Server instance + Traefik using ansible:

```
- name: Create couchbase-server container
  vars:
    labels:
      - key: "traefik.enable"
        value: "true"
      - key: "traefik.http.routers.{{ env_name }}_{{ service_name }}_server.rule"
        value: "Host(`{{ couchbase.server_url }}`)"
      - key: "traefik.http.routers.{{ env_name }}_{{ service_name }}_server.entrypoints"
        value: "websecure"
      - key: "traefik.http.routers.{{ env_name }}_{{ service_name }}_server.tls.certresolver"
        value: "myresolver"
      - key: "traefik.http.services.{{ env_name }}_{{ service_name }}_server.loadbalancer.server.port"
        value: "8091"
      - key: "traefik.http.services.{{ env_name }}_{{ service_name }}_server.loadbalancer.server.scheme"
        value: "http"
  community.docker.docker_container:
    name: "{{ env_name }}_{{ service_name }}_server"
    image: couchbase-server
    state: started
    restart_policy: unless-stopped
    hostname: "couchbase-server"
    working_dir: /opt/couchbase
    tty: true
    interactive: true
    entrypoint: [""]
    command: sh -c "/opt/couchbase/init/init-cbserver.sh"
    volumes:
      - "{{ docker_volumes_path }}/{{ env_name }}_{{ service_name }}_server:/opt/couchbase/var"
    networks:
      - name: "{{ env_name }}_{{ service_name }}"
        aliases:
          - "{{ env_name }}_{{ service_name }}_server"
    env:
      # All environment variables to configure Couchbase
      # COUCHBASE_...
    labels: "{{ labels | items2dict }}"
```

The problem is that there is a long list of ports which need to be accessible (https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/install/install-ports.html), so I have to somehow publish them all using traefik but under the same domain, so `host:port`. How can I do this? I have multiple environments (so multiple Couchbase instances), so I can't simply publish the ports and work with the IP.

Comment: maybe this [issue](https://community.traefik.io/t/docker-container-with-multiple-ports/4657) can help you, but it will be lots of lines